Social-application: Broadcast auth take too long
I want to build a social application using Laravel 11, React and Reverb for websoket, I got this problem when connect to multiple channel for each conversation, each channel require auth, and it very slow, so I have to wait it finished to send another request to backend.
Code For Backend
// channels.php
Broadcast::channel('message.user.{userId1}-{userId2}', function (User $user, int $userId1, int $userId2) {
    return $user->id === $userId1 || $user->id === $userId2 ? $user  : null;
});

Broadcast::channel('message.group.{groupId}', function (User  $user, int $groupId) {
    return $user->groups->contains('id', $groupId) ?  $user  : null;
});

Front End
Navbar.jsx
        useEffect(() => {
          conversations.forEach((conversation) => {
              let  channel = `message.group.${conversation.id}`;
  
              if(conversation.is_user){
                  channel = `message.user.${[
                      parseInt(user.id),
                      parseInt(conversation.id),
                  ]
                  .sort((a,b) => a - b)
                  .join("-")}`;
              }
  
              Echo.private(channel)
              .error((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
              })
              .listen("SocketMessage" ,  (e) =>  {
                  console.log("SocketMessage", e);
                  const message = e.message;
                  emit("message.created",  message);
                  if(message.sender_id  === user.id)
                  {
                      return;
                  }
                  emit("newMessageNotifiation", {
                      user: message.sender,
                      group_id: message.group_id,
                      message:
                      message.messgae || 
                      `Shared ${
                          message.attachments.length ===  1
                          ? "an attachemnt"
                          :  message.attachemnts.length +
                          " attachemnts"
                      }`,
                  });
              })
          })
          return () => {
              conversations.forEach((conversation) => {
                  let channel  = `message.group.${conversation.id}`;
  
                  if(conversation.is_user){
                      channel = `message.user.${[parseInt(user.id),  parseInt(conversation.id), ]
                          .sort((a,b) => a - b)
                          .join("-")
                      }`;
                  }
                  Echo.leave(channel);
              })
          };
  
      }, [conversations])

ChatLayout.jsx
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMessages = async () => {
      if (conversation) {
        const type = conversation.group_id ? 'group' : 'user';
        try {
          const response = a[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/A2KIx7j8.png)wait fetch(`/${type}/${conversation.id}`);
          const data = await response.json();
          if (data.selectedConversation) {
            setSelectedConversation(data.selectedConversation);
          } else {
            console.warn('No selectedConversation in the response');
          }
          setLocalMessages(data.messages || []);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching messages:', error);
        }
      }
    };
    fetchMessages();
  }, [conversation]);


When start project  or  reload, it will hear all channel relate to user,
When I click conversation to fetch all messages of it, if all auth channels not finished it will have to wait.
So my question is how I can fetch all messages without to wait all that auth channel finished
Image of network in console
I tried implement Promise and await, sync but it not worked

To optimize the process of connecting to multiple channels and avoid the delay caused by waiting for each channel to authenticate before fetching messages, you can parallelize the connections and the message fetching process.

Thanks for your comment, with your way some  time it reduce a lot of time but some time it not, or maybe I do some thing wrong with parallelize, Instead I only connect to channel when neccessary, so user only connect  to  channel when click to any conversation so it not take much time anymore, thanks for your help.
